# Looping through XML node using ForEach loop container via SSIS

Tags: xml, xpath, ssis, foreach-loop-container

Below is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <DataResult>
  <Data>
   <Name lang="eng">Reshma</Name>
   <Birth Date>1988-09-23T00:00:00</Birth Date>
  </Data>
 <Data>
   <Name lang="eng">Rahul</Name>
   <Birth Date>1991-09-23T00:00:00</Birth Date>
 </Data>
</DataResult>
```

I am trying to read this XML node value into the for each loop container, below is the my for each loop container setting,

[image]

Now I want to read that **Name** node value from above XML file and enter that value into database, can't I take a single variable first read the first **Name** node value into it and update the database and again rewrite the same variable by another **Name** node and update the database, since my main xml file is going to have n numbers of **Name** node.

My main aim is to read the xml file node into foreach loop, tried lot for it but unable to get the solution, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure you actually *need* the foreach container. Why not just read the whole file via the "XML Source" then use a "OLE DB Command" (which will be executed once for every row of data) and use an UPDATE statement with the appropriate WHERE condition? (If you have any questions of how to do this just let me know)

Comment: @TsSkTo.. when I am using XML source, I am not able to get the Name value in OLEDB Destination, it's showing some warning like no maximum length was specified for xml source.output[Name].columns[lang] with external data type system.string. The ssis data flow task data type "DT_WSTR" with a length of 255 will be used and also why should I make use of sql command, can't I directly insert data into database via OLEDB destination..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution which may be dodging the actual question.

Like I mentioned in the comments, I dont think you actually need the "foreach container". Use The "XML Source" to directly import all of your data. Next, as per your "DT_WSTR" error I would advise you to use either a "Data Conversion" or a "Derived Column" component to add a maximum length to your Columns.

[image]

Finally, you can use the "OLE DB Destination" if you are *inserting* the data into a table. I was under the impression that you wanted to *update* some existing data, in which case, I have always used an "OLE DB Command" with an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @TsSkTo... Thanks a lottt,it worked and so simple solution, was trying very hard with execute sql task,for each loop and all but in mean time, I learned a lot.Thank you once again.